# OnTouchListener fires touch events for a view, but OnClickListener does not

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

My situation is this: I have a small form which, when clicked, expands into a larger form.  I initially don't want any elements in the small form to be focused, so I create an invisible LinearLayout which takes focus when the Activity is created.  If I expand the small form into a larger form, one of the elements displayed is an ImageButton which I would like the user to be able to click.

What's weird is that if I expand the form from a small form without focusing on one of the other elements, my ImageButton does not receive any Click events.  If I put an `OnClickListener` onto the `ImageButton` then what happens is that all of the clicks onto my button are batched up and then sent once an EditText in the form takes focus.  However, if I attach an `OnTouchListener` onto that `ImageButton`, then both the MOTION_UP and MOTION_DOWN events are received by the listener and can be acted on.

The XML for my `ImageButton` is simply.

```
<merge>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zip_code_edittext"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/zip_code_edittext"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/select_country" />
```

I've tried setting `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` to no avail.  Any idea as to what could be happening here?

The whole XML file (with a bunch of un-fun elements removed) is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/invisible"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <requestFocus />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- A bunch of stuff unrelated to this particular situation -->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/photo_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/second_rl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

         <!-- A lot of things related to photos which are uninteresting for the purpose of this -->
       </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/small_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/first_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="?baseGapSize"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/last_name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@id/last_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="?baseGapSize"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/last_name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="?baseGapSize"
                android:hint="@string/opentable_email"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="?baseGapSize"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hidden_signup_fields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="?baseGapSize">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/problem_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zip_code_edittext"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/zip_code_edittext"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/select_country" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@id/zip_code_edittext"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/flag_selector"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:paddingRight="?largeGapSize" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/zip_code_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/zip_code_edittext"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/zip_code_edittext"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="?imageGapSize"
                    android:layout_marginRight="?imageGapSize"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/SubtitleText" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="?baseGapSize">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/gender_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="?baseGapSize"
                    android:gravity="right" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/gender_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="0px"
                    android:prompt="@string/create_account_gender" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/gender_button"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gender_button"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:text="@string/gender"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/SubtitleText"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gender_optional"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/gender_button"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gender_button"
                    android:layout_marginRight="?largeGapSize"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:text="@string/optional"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/SubtitleText"
                    android:textColor="@color/hint_foreground_light" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="?baseGapSize">

                <!-- A bunch of stuff that's unimportant -->
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/signup_button"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/tablet_max_button_size"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/sign_up_button_padding"
                    android:text="@string/sign_up"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/LargeDarkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/terms_of_service"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/signup_button"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/LargeLightText" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

That layout then gets put into a `ScrollView`

Comment: would you post the whole xml file ?

Comment: Added the full file to the question.

Comment: does the gender button and the signup button work?

Comment: They do not, interesting.

Comment: could you post the full code?

Comment: Remove the small linear layout and try again just to check if the buttons will work or not

Comment: @3amoura yup, I removed the `hidden_signup_fields` LinearLayout and manually hid some internal views.  When I showed those views again, I was able to properly click on them.

Comment: Sure that will work, but I'm wondering why this is happening.  I don't want to blindly hack around on things when there may be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Top `Linear Layout` and hide the requested views and show them when you need them.